# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar la última letra de una cadena de texto con JavaScrpt al hacer click en un botón?

Tags: javascript, css3, string, substring, math

### ¿Cómo puedo eliminar la última letra de una cadena de texto con JavaScrpt al hacer click en un botón?

Como `Desarrollador Web` autodidacta, tengo momentos en los que me pongo a hacer proyectos con HTML, CSS, JavaScript o jQuery. En este caso estoy haciendo una calculadora, ya tengo el diseño y todo, pero tengo un problema con JS. *Lo que quiero hacer es que al momento de que yo presione un botón en específico, elimine el último número ingresado.*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Hasta el momento solo tengo el párrafo que es donde muestro los números que voy escribiendo y el botón al que voy a hacer click:**

```html
<p id="input"></p>
```

```js
var borrarElÚltimo = document.getElementById('del');

// Borrar la última letra
borrarElÚltimo.onclick = () => {
  .replace();
  .substr();
  .substring();
}
```

Hasta el momento solo he probado con esos métodos de arriba, pero nada de lo que se me viene a la mente funciona, o no como me gustaría, **necesito ayuda para saber cómo eliminar el último número el párrafo, Gracias...**

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar la función `substring` o `slice` también.

[`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/substring) recibe 2 parámetros, el primero indica a partir de que posición copiar la cadena y el segundo cuantos caracteres tomar

[`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/slice) también recibe 2 parámetros la diferencia es que recibe 2 índices, desde donde y hasta donde copiar la cadena.  Tiene la peculiaridad de que puedes usar valores negativo en el segundo índice para indicar que empiece a contar desde el último caracter.

Un ejemplo pequeño de como borrar el último caracter:

```js
document
  .getElementById('borrar')
  .addEventListener('click', () => {
    var texto = document.getElementById('texto');
    texto.value = texto.value.substring(0, texto.value.length - 1);
               // alternativa:
               // texto.value.slice(0, -1);
  });
```

```html
<input id="texto" value="Prueba" />
<button id="borrar">Borrar &larr;</button>
```